# Switching Amazon Connect agents offline automatically

Tags: amazon-connect

We've got a contact centre on Amazon Connect. However, our agents keep forgetting to log off or switch to offline when they leave or close the browser, which messes up with user experience and metrics.

Manually, through the "Real-time metrics" report of type "Agents" we can switch each agent to "Offline" using UI. But there is no API for that. Anyone figured out how to automate that? Basically,  we want to switch offline any agent who is either in Missed state for >1 hour, or ACW for >1 hour, or in Error for >1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Amazon Connect's blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-agent-status-offline-ccp/) - they talk about how to switch Agent's status to Offline when close browser (you need to custom the default CCP).

Amazon Connect also has Agent Event Stream that describe about Agent when has any change from Agent or interval every 2 minutes.
If you want to customize Agent status after 1 hour, I think you should have a Agent table on DynamoDB, then store agent information and the last time Missed, ACW, Error, ... and create the background tasks for checking and updating.